# Using c# to write adobe plug ins

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, adobe, add-in

from my understand, in order to write adobe plugin, we have to use c++ and the adobe sdk to write the adobe plug ins.

is that possible to use c#, link with adobe sdk to write adobe plug ins?

Comment: You have to use C, but you can make the implementation in C++. (i.e. you have to use naked functions and must either compile them with a C compiler or declare them `extern "C"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with Acrobat as sunil5715 mentioned.. BUT I had the SDK for Adobe Illustrator v4. Back then you had to use Motorola's IDE named Code Warriors. You wont be able to use C# if you expect it your plugin to run on a Mac.

Maybe if you wrote a version in Mono it might run on a mac, but that is obviously not ideal.

Couple of notes (for Illustrator atleast) the code is unmanaged C++ and mixing unmanaged with managed code isn't the best practice. Also when you see the SDKs for Illustrator, Photoshop, After Effects you will see how dam good their (Adobe's) code is. Its spectacular! EXTREMELY good quality and is much better than the production code in many Microsoft products. So unless its a simple plugin I think you will need the low level abilities of C++.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! :)

It's a vast topic but you can begin with

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf

Page 21

Comment: That PDF, it appears, is only available to a select club of people. Could you elaborate your answer?